# Write to a txt file in pythonanywhere?

Tags: pythonanywhere

Hello i'm a beginner in pythonanywhere.

I'm trying to write to a txt file but it isn't working, this is my code:

```
write_file = open("/home/Debonnet/test/test.txt", "a")
write_file.write("test2")
write_file.close
```

But nothing is being written to the file..I tried "w" instead of "a" also but nothing chan

Comment: you have the write permission there??

Comment: Yes i think, how can i check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modern Python prefers the `with` idiom:

```
with open("/home/Debonnet/test/test.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("test2")
```

The `with` means Python will magically call close for you automatically at the end of the block, even if anything in there throws an exception

On "w" vs "a", the latter means "append", so it won't overwrite previous contents...

Answer (score 0):

`close` is a method. You need to call it like this: `write_file.close()`